# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error" in a simple program

Tags: java

I recently installed Visual Studio Code and tried to run a 
simple program

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

}

but I got this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at HelloWorld.main(nush.java:3)
```

I'm using java development kit 11.0.1 and this is my launch.json

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - HelloWorld",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "mainClass": "HelloWorld",
        "args": ""
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Looks like your class name and the file name differs. Make sure to rename everything to same e.g. `class HelloWorld` in `HelloWorld.java` file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: Also, please do not post images of code or errors, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`public class HelloWorld` must be saved in a file named `HelloWorld.java`, not `nush.java`

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the steps below...
It solved my problem

In VS CODE...
Clean the java language server workplace

Answer (score -1):

Class name should be similar to the file name.
Refactor the file name as below or vice versa.
Class name = HelloWorld
File name = HelloWorld.java

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452129/2227743).